# How to create a Python Array Permutation with Structure

Tags: arrays, numpy, random, permutation

I want to create python array that have the numbers one to 42 in the first column and the numbers 1 and 3 in the second column, but with special conditions. I want that there are pairs of 1,3 and 3,1.

I actually got code that works, but it's pretty slow. Maybe anyone of you have a faster solution.

```
import numpy as np
import random

trials=np.linspace(1,42,42)
vec1=np.ones(21)
vec2=vec1+2
trial_types=np.concatenate((vec1,vec2))
isok=0
numb_run=1
while isok == 0:
    random.shuffle(trial_types)
    break_con = 0
    i=1
    while i <= len(trial_types):
        if trial_types[i] == trial_types[i - 1]:
            break_con = 1
        if break_con == 1:
            break
        i +=2
    numb_run+=1
    if break_con == 0:
        isok=1
print(trial_types)
print(numb_run)
```

I shuffle and compare an equal entry with an unequal and look if they are the same. If this on time happens i shuffles again. But it takes sometime until with this randomize it happens that the column I am trying to create looks like this:

```
[3. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1. 1. 3. 1. 3. 3. 1. 1. 3. 1. 3. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1. 1. 3.
 3. 1. 1. 3. 3. 1. 1. 3. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1. 3. 1.]
711799
```

And as you can see it takes 700K shuffles to get there.
Do you have any ideas how i can make it faster ?
I also tried with some kind of np.tile([1,3]) and np.tile([3,1]) but unfortunately 42/4 is not a equal number.

Cheers

Comment: Instead of shuffling the whole array of 42 values, shuffle just one pair ie 3,1 or 1,3 and the append that. until you get 42. Below code describes one way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
pairs = np.array([[3,1], [1,3]])
pairs[np.random.randint(2,size=21)].flatten()
array([3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3,
       3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3])
```

Each time you run you will get different results but still pairs of (3,1) and (1, 3)

---

Instead of shuffling the whole array of 42 values, shuffle just one pair ie 3,1 or 1,3 and the append that. until you get 42. Below code describes one way

```
np.r_[*[np.random.choice([1,3],2,replace = False)  for i in range(21)]]
array([3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1,
       1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer. Exectly this solves my Problem. Life can be so easy... Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but i sitll run into a problem here. The two pairs are not equally contributed. So is there a way to say, both times shell be occur the same amount?

Comment: @Fabian the two are equaly distributed its only that the number of runs ie 21 is minimal. If you increase the number of runs to 1000 and check the distribution, each of the two is approximately 0.5, eg for 10 rands, you might end up having 7,3 or even 8,2 but for 100 you cannot get 70,30.. even 60,40 is very rare. So yes the distribution is equally likely. Just increase the sample size

Comment: Unfortunately i wanted to use your method for Vector with pairs [1,1] and [2,2] and size 42, and there it needs to be 100% equally distributed

Comment: @Fabian simple, generate a vector with equal integers and shuffle them. if use `np.random.shuffle` Also notice that 42 is not divisible by 4, so you cannot have EXACTLY 100% equal distribution. If you had 48, then you could have 12 pairs of (1,3) and another 12 pairs of (3,1) ending up with a vector of 48 elements

Comment: Hey it's not that simple. for the vector with the pairs [1,3] and [3,1] it's only important that the numbers 1 and 3 are equally distributed. Ofc 42 is not good dividable by 3. 
But my overall goal is/was to create a (84,4) Matrix what i got done now. The first coloumn was numbers 1 to 84 , second coloumb pairs [1,1] and [2,2], third coloum the pairs [1,3] [3,1] and fourth coloum numbers from 1,2,3 equally occuring shuffled. If you are intrested in my code how i create this matrix i can sen you it or post it. Cheers

Comment: @Fabian, still simple. Just have a shuffled vector of positions 0 and 1 with equal outcomes, then use that get the values [1,1] and [2,2]. ie look at the first example. But instead of using randint, use shuffle. ie `a = np.r_[np.zeros(21, int), np.ones(21,int)]; np.random.shuffle(a);  np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])[a].flatten()`

Comment: You are right, that is much simpler then that what i've done. Thanks!